# Entity Framework Query Join issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, join

I'm using an AJAX query to call a function that references a model.

So far it returns details to a user table, which all works fine. The problem is, I have a one to many relationship to another table.

Person - PersonId goes to joining table - personId linked to potentially multiple colourIds - colourId links to colour table.

So three tables - person, favourite colour and colour are involved.

I want to include a join in my original query but I'm having difficulty. The query:

```
TechTestEntities testTechObj = new TechTestEntities();
                     var Result = from p in testTechObj.People
                     join fp in testTechObj.FavouriteColours on p.PersonId equals fp.PersonId
                     join c in testTechObj.Colours on fp.ColourId equals c.ColourId
                     select p;
```

When I run this I get the error that 'The entity type FavouriteColours is not part of the model for the current context.'

I have also added FavouriteColours to the model like so:

```
 public virtual DbSet<FavouriteColours> FavouriteColours { get; set; }
```

All the tables should be included in the ADO model, so I'm not sure what the problem is and how to retrieve the colour names through a join.

Edit:

Model code

```
    namespace techTest4
        {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
        using techTest4.Models;

    public partial class TechTestEntities : DbContext
    {
        public TechTestEntities()
            : base("name=TechTestEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        //public virtual DbSet<FavouriteColours> FavouriteColours { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the class definition of whatever type "testTechObj" is, along with the class where your "DbSet"s are defined

Comment: Is "FavouriteColours" also out commented in the code, that you run?

Comment: I do not really understand what functionality you are trying to achieve here - are you looking to extract all people from the database?

Comment: I recommend that you update your EF model using the model interface. Doing by hand can lead to many problems.

Comment: @J.N. FavouriteColours wasn't commented out when I tested it but was left like that when it didn't fix the underlying issue. I currently have a table with the people's details from the database; I want to add a join in the query to get the names of their favourite colour(s). According to the model interface, all three tables should already be included.

Comment: Since OnModelCreating is not run, I don't think the model is correct anymore, which would lead to this error. Update your model from database or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to guess what your classes look like, but take a look at this code:
( https://dotnetfiddle.net/TVqzse )

This snippet is the most interesting for you:

```
var favoriteColours = people.SelectMany(p => p.FavouriteColours);

foreach(var favoriteColour in favoriteColours) {    
    System.Console.WriteLine(favoriteColour.Color.ColorName);
}
```

This uses LINQ to extract the favourite colours of all people, and you should be able to do exactly the same in Entity Framework.

Comment: @user3316147 - You're welcome. Take a look here to see more examples of LINQ queries: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj573936(v=vs.113).aspx